# MYSQL Mac OSX Snow Leopard, mysql.sock being removed while mysql is being used

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-snow-leopard, mysql.sock

Sometimes I can use MYSQL all day, and other times for just 10 minutes before I get a "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)" error. If I try to restart MYSQL server it just hangs and crashes, the only way I can fix the problem is by restarting my computer.

1. Adding /tmp/mysql.sock to my.cnf has made no difference
2. Once the problem occurs the mysql.sock file is no where on the file system, so it is not a directory issue.

Any ideas what is going on? Restarting my computer every time it occurs is very unproductive!